# finding records which don't have corresponding records with an extension at the end

Tags: sql

Id like to find records with (.XX) extension at the end which don't have corresponding records without an extension (.XX) at the end. Id like to use the "exists" or "not exists" solution if possible as I'm puzzled why mine gives no output.

**input**

```
col_a
value1.XX
value1
value2.XX
value3
```

** expected output**

```
col_a
value2.XX
```

**code**

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 as a
where
right (table1.[col_a],3) = ".XX"
and  exists(
select 1 from table1 b where  Left(a.[col_a], Len(a.[col_a]) - 3)  = b.[col_a]
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm. You

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.col_a like '%.XX' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table1 tt1
                  where t1.col_a = tt1.col_a || '.XX'
                 );
```

Note:  You have not specified your database so this uses the ISO/ANSI standard `||` for string concatenation. You can check your RDBMs's documentation for the correct concatenation technique.

Comment: Your query returns both value1.XX and value2.xx, while OP only wants to return value2.xx (since value1.xx has a corresponding value1). I think you mixed up your tt1.col_a and t1.col_a in the subquery. I went ahead and requested the edit.